# Multiple choice question about the domain of $f/g$ in terms of the domains of $f$ and $g$

Tags: functions

If functions $f$ and $g$ have domains $Df$ and $Dg$ respectively, then the domain of $f / g$ is given by

(A) the union of $Df$ and $Dg$
(B) the intersection of $Df$ and $Dg$
(C) the intersection of $Df$ and $Dg$ without the zeros of function $g$
(D) None of the above

Comment: What have you thought about? Given this is a multiple choice problem, the answer is almost literally staring at you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of any composite functions $$f\pm g,~ fg,~f/g,~g/f$$ can be achived by finding $D(f)\cap D(g)$ except that for the fraction forms we should exclude what @Clayton noted nimbly.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can divide by any real number except...

Comment: Nice hint +1$$$$